# Find matching content in two compressed audio files

Tags: ios, audio, audio-processing

I am trying to find the time range of any matching content in two audio files. An example of use is:

I have two mp3 files stripped from a tv show. At the start of the tv show they have a "previously on" recap, and then the show's theme tune and then the actual show.

The recap part is of a variably length, but the theme tune is always the same. It may not be the same when comparing bytes though due to compression on the whole file.

My goal is to compare two mp3 files of the show, find the common theme tune and get the time range of it so it is possible to know where the actual content of the show starts.

There is also the possibility of multiple common matches in the files, e.g. an advert that is on both tv shows, it would be good to find these as well.

I'll be doing this on iOS.

What things should I be looking into, fourier transforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way to find a signal (audio or otherwise) within another is with [a cross correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) and the efficient way to do this is in the frequency domain, where the expensive O(n^2) matrix multiplication of the naive method becomes an O(n) complex conjugate multiply.

On iOS you can use the `Accelerate` framework to achieve this, with the calls

- `vDSP_fft_zrip` to transform each of your audio files to the frequency domain
- `vDSP_zvcmul` to multiply the resulting signals together
- and `vDSP_fft_zrip` transform the product back to the time domain

The index of the largest absolute value in this final result gives you the time lag of the best match of one signal within the other.

This answer glosses over a lot of details, including packing (which complicates the multiplication), signal padding, decoding the mp3s to the float/double format that the signal processing functions expect, flattening stereo to mono, and breaking the cross correlation into smaller, overlapping chunks as you probably don't want to load the entire tv show audio into memory.

Sorry about that. I'd love to write a small open source library that does this. That would be worth 100 answers like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into what you have mentioned and see what I can do.